# Q: How do I set up a VPN to a PC in Windows Azure?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, azure

I have followed these [Steps](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/10/how-to-install-vpn-on-windows-server-2008-r2/) on setting up a VPN Connection on Window Server 2008  but I cannot connect. I got this error :Error 800. When I tried to follow what this [Troubleshooting Guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rrasblog/archive/2009/08/12/troubleshooting-common-vpn-related-errors.aspx) says, still can't connect.

I have the Windows Server 2008 on Azure. **How do I go about it?**

If there is another useful resource on installing VPN on the server, I will highly appreciate.

Comment: Must ask, did you open the ports on the cloud service access control list?

Comment: Yes I did, Ports:1701, 1723 and 47.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this is a normal  behavior because **Azure apparently does not allow the GRE Protocol** to pass its network.

Note that the GRE is not a TCP or UDP protocol, it's more than that, you can't just go to a firewall and open the port 47 and expect it to work, the firewall it self must support a higher level of routing, you can read all about it here: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos12.1/topics/concept/gre-tunnel-services.html.

Your best shot for this to work is to use one of these solutions:

1. **Create a Point-to-Site VPN**: this will allow your computers to connect to the Azure virtual network and be part of it, the VPN gateway will be the Azure firewalls and not your VM, I personally prefer this solution since it supports a better SLA than your solution, more details about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/)
2. **Configure SSTP VPN Access**: this will change the way the VPN work on your server to use the port 443 which is universally allowed, instead of using the ports 1701, 1723 and 47, this VPN connection and routing will be managed from inside your VM, since this is all configured inside a VM, the SLA in this case will be bound to the SLA of the VM it self,  more details about it are here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731352(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lemmi try the second option.